# Set maximum value for the progress bar to match length of queue.

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I would like to visualize how a queue when accessed by two reader threads and a writer thread grows and shrinks, with help of a progressbar in mainform. I will use a delegate to invoke the progress bar in main form and set its value to Queue.Value ( Toys.lenght). The progressbar does not behave as stated, it does not grow all the way and the lenght variables does not either.

```
     public class Buffer
     {
        private delegate void Display(int v, ProgressBar f );
        private Queue<Toy> Toys = new Queue<Toy>(); 
        private object MyLock = new object();
        private int max;
        private int lenght; 
        private ProgressBar progressbar1; 
        public Buffer(ProgressBar r)
        {
            this.progressbar1 = r; 
            this.max = 10;
            this.lenght = Toys.Count; 

        }
        public void writeMethod(Toy toy)
        {
            lock (MyLock)
            {
               if (Toys.Count == max)
               {
                   Monitor.Wait(MyLock); 
               }

               Toys.Enqueue(toy); 
               Monitor.PulseAll(MyLock);  
                progressbar1.Invoke(new Display(Disp), new object[] {Toys.Count, progressbar1});
                MessageBox.Show("Que contains these items" + lenght); 

            }

        }

        public void readMethod()
        {
            lock (MyLock)
            {
                if(Toys.Count == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(MyLock); 
                }
                Toys.Dequeue(); 
                Monitor.PulseAll(MyLock); 
            }

        }
        public void Disp(int I, ProgressBar l)
        {
            progressbar1.Value = I; 


        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure what is your question. What is the `Minimum` and `Maximum` of progress bar set to? And most importantly do you ever add more than one item to `Toys`?

Comment: I never manage to add anything to the que, and yet the progress bar grows about 10 % of the bar. My first thought was that the progressbar migh have some settings that I need to adjust for example: make the lenght of the bar to 100 and that it should be filled with 10 % when one item is added to the queue. Does this make any sense?

Comment: My crystal ball says that max = 10 and progressbar1.Maximum = 100.  Wildly inappropriate UI btw, the larger the value the *less* progress you made.

Comment: What is the value of progressbar1.Maximum? Check it just before the invoke. 10 items is 10% of the default which I think is 100. Set this.progressbar1.Maximum = 10. Also try a bigger or smaller array of toys to see if it affects the size.

Comment: Ok I understand, I just did this and now it works perfectly.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the variable lenght, use count instead. Change Progressbar default setting for maximum size from 100 to 10 to match size of the queue Toys. In Disp method change from = I to += I;

```
   {
    public class Buffer
    {
        private delegate void Display(int v, ProgressBar f );
        private Queue<Toy> Toys = new Queue<Toy>(); 
        private object MyLock = new object();
        private int max;
        private int lenght; 
        private ProgressBar progressbar1; 
        public Buffer(ProgressBar r)
        {
            this.progressbar1 = r; 
            this.max = 10;
            this.lenght = Toys.Count; 

        }
        public void writeMethod(Toy toy)
        {
            lock (MyLock)
            {
               if (Toys.Count >= max)
               {
                   Monitor.Wait(MyLock);
               }

               if(Toys.Count <= max)
               {
                   Toys.Enqueue(toy); 
                  progressbar1.Invoke(new Display(Disp), new object[] {Toys.Count, progressbar1});
               }

                Monitor.PulseAll(MyLock);


                MessageBox.Show("Que contains these items" + Toys.Count); 
            }
        }

        public void readMethod()
        {
            lock (MyLock)
            {
                if(Toys.Count == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(MyLock); 
                }
                Toys.Dequeue(); 
                Monitor.PulseAll(MyLock); 

            }

        }
        public void Disp(int I, ProgressBar l)
        {
            progressbar1.Value += I; 

        }
    }
}
```